# What is the bounty expires message trying to tell me, when it shows up on a question with no answers?

Tags: discussion, bounties, notifications

I got the notification that "Bounty expires in 3 days".

Now normally, 
I assume its purpose is to remind me to consider accepting an answer.

However, in this case there are no answers posted yet.
What is it reminding me to do then?

Answer (score 2):

It is reminding you that you may need to apply some attention to your question in order for it to attract potential answerers.

In 3 days your bounty expires so as soon as possible I think you should edit it to try to make what you are asking clearer and more answerable.

For example, if your question asks more than one question (i.e. it is too broad), then decide which is more important to you, and remove the other.  There may be a potential answerer of one question who does not answer because they do not have an answer to both.

Comment: Fair enough.
Unfortunately, I think I have done all I can do make that happen already. (Plenty of upvotes, and comments indication people understand what I am asking).

Comment: Without a link to it I cannot offer advice on what you may be able to do to make it clearer and more answerable.  If people know what you are asking and are not answering you may need to reduce what you are asking for - perhaps it has more than one aspect within it.

Comment: https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5568/2978

Comment: You are asking two questions there.  The first edit that I would make would be to decide which was more important to me, and to ask just that.

Comment: Thanks, on another look neither of the dot pointed questions were actually the questions I mean to ask (that was the one in the title.).

The one was actually  speculation about a possible answer, and the other was suggestions for what a good answer would feature.
I have rewritten, thanks again.

Comment: Your site may be different, but I always like to see the single question indicated by a question mark - perhaps  `Has there  been a change in the relative frequency of "limited third-person point of view", vs "omniscient third person point of view"?`